# how does new exchanges order books work?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, exchanges, cryptography, exchange-order

**When a new exchange is launched and it doesn't have many users, how does it managed an order book? how can they match orders when there's not enough of them?**

Answer (score 0):

When there are matching orders then there are matches.

When there are no matching orders then there are no matches.

Comment: so what happens to the first orders that there's no match for them?

Comment: @pardis.ti if they are limit orders they just stay on the book, if they are market orders they don’t fill

Comment: that does not sound good for a new business, is there anyway to resolve this? going this way the exchange will never grow because it can't start filling the orders and the users rather change their exchange. so what can they do?

Comment: Hi anion, while your answer is not wrong, it doesn't seem to explain the issue well enough to resolve the question. Could you please add more explanation to your answer?

Comment: @pardis.ti Sounds like your real question is how to market/advertize your exchange. I'm afraid that'd be off-topic here.